# XSLT group nodes by key provided in element

Tags: xslt

I got a nasty XML where nodes are not grouped what I want and I am trying to find a way to group them by provided `<master_key>` in the node:

**raw xml**:

```
<root>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>388300-56</kod>
      <description>50cm</description>
      <master_key>388300MK</master_key>
      <kategorie/>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>388300-53</kod>
      <description>53cm</description>
      <master_key>388300MK</master_key>
      <kategorie/>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>388300MK</kod>
      <description>Master</description>
      <kategorie/>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>388399-56</kod>
      <description>56cm</description>
      <master_key>388399MK</master_key>
      <kategorie/>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>388399-57</kod>
      <description>57cm</description>
      <master_key>388399MK</master_key>
      <kategorie/>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>388399MK</kod>
      <description>Master 2</description>
      <kategorie/>
   </zasoba>
</root>
```

There, product variants are separated in individual elements, but I would like to move under the the master element (defined by `master_key`) under a new element name `<variant>`.

Output should be look like this:

```
<root>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>388300MK</kod>
      <description>Master 2</description>
      <kategorie/>
      <variant>
         <kod>388300-56</kod>
         <description>50cm</description>
         <master_key>388300MK</master_key>
         <kategorie/>
      </variant>
      <variant>
         <kod>388300-53</kod>
         <description>53cm</description>
         <master_key>388300MK</master_key>
         <kategorie/>
      </variant>
   </zasoba>
   <zasoba>
      <kod>388399MK</kod>
      <description>Master</description>
      <kategorie/>
      <variant>
         <kod>388399-56</kod>
         <description>56cm</description>
         <master_key>388399MK</master_key>
         <kategorie/>
      </variant>
      <variant>
         <kod>388399-57</kod>
         <description>57cm</description>
         <master_key>388399MK</master_key>
         <kategorie/>
      </variant>
   </zasoba>
</root>
```

Comment: You have a couple of possibilities. You could look over the elements where the text() of `<kod>` ends in 'MK'. You could find the master keys from their children with the `<master_key>` element (which the master doesn't have). You can loop through the nodes where the description starts with 'Master'. **What have you tried?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fortunately XPath is flexible enough to select the grouping population in the order you want and the grouping key with the value existing:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="root">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:for-each-group select="zasoba[not(master_key)], zasoba[master_key]" group-by="(master_key, kod)[1]">
              <xsl:copy>
                  <xsl:apply-templates/>
                  <xsl:apply-templates select="tail(current-group())"/>
              </xsl:copy>
          </xsl:for-each-group>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="zasoba">
      <variant>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </variant>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/ejivdHb

Comment: I wish I had 1/10 of your knowledge. :)